# React AgGrid - Row Style based on conditions from the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am using AgGrid for React and I am using class-style react components - not functional components.

My goal is to render the `cellStyle` based on props conditions.

However, when I want to render it, it renders without even the props are loaded.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you put your code here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to call [`GridApi.refreshCells()`](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/view-refresh/#example-refresh-cells) to apply the change after updating the column's `cellStyle`:

```
const columnDefs = React.useMemo(
  () => [
    {...}
    {
      headerName: "Age",
      field: "age",
      cellStyle: props.styles
        ? { backgroundColor: "pink" }
        : { backgroundColor: "white" }
    }
  ],
  [props.styles]
);

React.useEffect(() => {
  gridApi?.refreshCells({ force: true });
}, [props.styles]);
```

### Live Demo

#### Class component

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

#### Functional component

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: how would this look like for a class component ? Not sure about that.

Comment: @employee you can check whether your props changed using [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) and call `GridApi.refreshCells()` if the new and old prop is different. Do you need an example?

Comment: let´s assume i pass a list as a props to a class component. I want to check if a value of a certain row (e.g. 'accountId') is in this list. If yes, colorize it 'green' otherwise 'blue'. How would this work with the refreshcells'refreshCells'?

Comment: @employee do you want to colorize the cell based on the data inside only? or does it depend on the external props?

Comment: @employee Not sure if this is what you want but I updated to the class component

Comment: it should be based on the props. So if the 'param.data.id' is in the list (provided by the props) then render it green, otherwise blue